# SSRS Date format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a question regarding the date format in SSRS.

For Example I have data like this [image: Sample]
 I want to display the Days of the Week for the sample dates attached I want to get `Sunday`, `Monday`. 
Is it Possible? Then how? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Yes, it's possible through the date/time formatting functions and strings in SSRS. What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @alroc I've got already what I want. through sql script getting `datename` of the date I want to display. anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this though the `WeekdayName` function with this expression on your cell:
`=WeekdayName( DatePart( "w", Fields!Date.Value ) )`

Where `Fields!Date.Value` is the field in your dataset which contains the dates.